# Can't find Jetty WebSocket classes after adding the libraries in classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, websocket, jetty

I'm trying to use Jetty to communicate with a remote Server, using websockets.
I'm developing it in Eclipse, but i can't compile any sample code.
That's what i've done

I downloaded the latest version of Jetty, and i've added start.jar in the classpath.
That's what i've included in the sample class

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.Session;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.StatusCode;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.OnWebSocketClose;
```

and some more. The problem is that Eclipse can't resolve those imports. What should i do?

Comment: It is unclear from the question if you are wanting to write a Jetty WebSocket server or a Jetty WebSocket client.  Either way, you will need jars other than `start.jar`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove the `start.jar` from your project, that's just a bootstrap jar for starting the standalone Jetty distribution.

The JARs you need are in the `${jetty.dist}/lib/websockets/` directory.

```
[joakim@lapetus jetty-distribution-9.0.4.v20130625]$ ls -1 lib/websocket/
websocket-api-9.0.4.v20130625.jar
websocket-client-9.0.4.v20130625.jar
websocket-common-9.0.4.v20130625.jar
websocket-server-9.0.4.v20130625.jar
websocket-servlet-9.0.4.v20130625.jar
```

**All WebSocket Apps**

Always include in your project:

- `lib/websocket/websocket-api-9.0.4.v20130625.jar`

**WebSocket Client Requirements**

Add the following to your project:

- `lib/websocket/websocket-client-9.0.4.v20130625.jar`
- `lib/websocket/websocket-common-9.0.4.v20130625.jar`
- `lib/jetty-io-9.0.4.v20130625.jar`
- `lib/jetty-util-9.0.4.v20130625.jar`

**WebSocket Servlet Requirements**

If you are writing a WebSocket server that will hook into your WAR/WebApp, then you'll need:

- `websocket-servlet-9.0.4.v20130625.jar`

You will never need `websocket-server-9.0.4.v20130625.jar` as that is an internal / implementation specific JAR that the Jetty Server uses to provide its support for WebSockets.

Comment: One probolem: when i try to launch the app with a thread of a jetty class, i get this error "The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle. And a second one "The type org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"Fix the build path then try building this project": should i do something more?

Comment: Solved, last 2 jars needed. But i get this runtime error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/client/WebSocketClient : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0, really dont know what it is

Comment: "major.minor version 51.0" means Java 7 is required.

Answer (score -1):

Please go thru the client [API](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-websocket-client-api.html) The jar listed there must be in your classpath.

Comment: Can you please be more precise? I can't understand sorry

Comment: Assuming that you are new to Java. Your class has to have access to other .class files that are bundled in the jar files listed in the tutorial. The link I provided has a sample implementation of a websocket client. All you need to do is copy-paste and run. You may want to download the jar file from search.maven.org and add it to the project libraries.

Comment: the current project is over 10k lines long :P anyway.. i've already pasted that example, but org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.ClientUpgradeRequest;
org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.WebSocketClient; still cannot be resolved... i downloaded jetty from there http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/dist/

Comment: i included it as follows menu => project => properties => java build path => add external jar => added start.jar

Comment: Did you try adding the websocket-client jar too following the same process ?

Comment: Yes, just done.. i've included both the jetty-all-7.6.2.v20120308.jar and the jetty-websocket-7.6.2.v20120308-tests.jar files

Comment: Please note i've succesfully added, before this, another jar to connect to a mysql DB.. i really cant figure the why of this problem..

Comment: For unresolved dependencies, try searching in a site like http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/  and add all relevant jars to your project  If it still doesn't work its an eclipse classpath issue. Try refreshing the project configuration and also try restarting eclipse from the shell with eclipse -clean

Comment: Uhm... in the project navigator i see all the needed jars, under the "referenced libraries"... i've also called the eclipse.exe -clear, but nothing happens :( also the same errors... cant resolve classes and that two imports

Comment: Wow. I just noticed i have to change Eclipse version and use m2e.... Done but nothing is changed. Now i'm using latest Eclipse IDE version