# How to make m2e plugin work on Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, plugins, m2e

I need to use jsr356 for websocket connection. I'm using Eclipse IDE (latest version) but i'am not able to use that library.

I have downloaded the proper m2e plugin from the Help tab in the main menu, then i have included the jsr356 JAR in my project (projext/properties/java build path / add external JARs), but nothing happens. My code still can't resolve some classes relative to a jsr356 exaple found on the internet.

Can you please explain me on how to make the jsr356 work on my Eclipse project?

The problem is that i cant figure out what's going on. First of all, i downloaded the jsr JAR (i dont remember the link, tell me if its important); at this point, the compiler told me it cant resolve some classes and includes. i've read some help links, i found i had to download the latest eclipse version. Done it, i went the next step: i clicked on main menu => help =>  eclipse marketplace and downloaded Maven Integration for Eclipse WTP (m2e-wtp). That's all.. i actually dont know what pom is. The project is a normal Eclipse project

Comment: can you please explain what exactly you have done. *How* have you included the jar in your project? what is your pom like? is your project mavenized?

Comment: can you give some concrete examples which classes is your project missing?

Answer (score 2):

m2e plugin is for Maven integration. [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) is a build/dependency management tool that is based on pom.xml configuration files.

It seems you're not using maven at all, so there's no point for you having m2e plugin, either.

What you need to do is

1. list out which classes are you actually missing
2. find out which .jar provides those classes ([findjar](http://findjar.com/index.x) web site can help there)
3. get that jar
4. figure out if you need the .jar also on runtime, or does the server provide it for you and you need it just development time
5. based on that information, either add it to build path or configure the .jar as a library to be deployed with your project

Comment: I'm trying to use Jetty right now, and something is missing again. Missing classes are WebSocketClient, ClientUpgradeRequest and the package Example(??) that are in the jerry example class. the source code is at this link http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-websocket-client-api.html And the copied class is SimpleEchoClient.java. Also the last two includes are missing - Thank you btw, really good answer

Comment: Ops, I can't find those classes on findjar.com

Comment: @mark those are Jetty-specific classes, you won't find them in any API. You have to include Jetty libraries in class path to get those. That is why the instructions on the page tell to add that maven dependency. You can do that, or if you still go without maven,copy the jar directly from [here](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.eclipse.jetty.websocket%7Cwebsocket-client%7C9.0.4.v20130625%7Cjar)

Comment: Problem solved here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17956357/cant-find-jetty-websocket-classes-after-adding-the-libraries-in-classpath Anyway, thank you, your explanation will be useful for the future!